# How to access shared folder through specific network adapter/device?

Tags: windows, networking, shared-folders

I have two Windows 10 machines. Both are connected to the a router via WiFi. The use a local IP of `192.168.1.xxx` and a subnet of `255.255.255.0`

I have recently set up an Ethernet connection between the two machines. In my network adapter settings, for the Ethernet connection, I set the IPv4 general settings to use the addresses of `10.0.0.1` and `10.0.0.2` with a subnet of `255.0.0.0`

Currently I can use the Explorer->Network to access shared files (e.g.: `Comp1` can see `Comp2/Users/myuser/`). When doing file transfers, etc. with the shared folders/files, how can I force the use of the Ethernet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force a connection through the wired connection, access the remote computer using the IP address bound to its wired network interface. For example, if the destination computer's wired interface has the IP address `10.0.0.2`, put `\\10.0.0.2` into File Explorer's address bar.  You can also access a share directly with `\\10.0.0.2\name-of-share`.

Additionally, you can edit your HOSTS file (located in the folder `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc`) to associate remote computer's wired IP address with a unique hostname. Then simply use this hostname when you want to access the machine via the cabled interface.

Otherwise, if you access the remote computer by its self-designated hostname, Windows will perform name resolution to convert the name into an IP address. Depending on which address is returned first by the name resolution process, Windows may or may not access the remote computer through the fastest connection.